# Checkbox with false value in form

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I need send with post `false` value of checkbox witch is not checked by default.
My checkbox is defined like this:

`<label><input type="checkbox" id="rez" name="rezerwowanie" value="false" />Rezerwowanie</label>`

And after submit I use that code to check if checkbox is checked or not:

```
$Reservation = $_POST['rezerwowanie'];
    if ($Reservation == false) {
        $Reservation = 0;
    } else
    {
        $Reservation = 1;
    }
```

It work when I check the checkbox but with not checked it don't work. What's the problem here?

Comment: $Reservation = "false" is not == false, should try `if ($Reservation == 'false')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox only sends a value to the server when it is activated. So when it is not checked, $_POST['rezerwowanie'] will not be there. Your code will need to account for this.  Checking to see if the array element isset will give you the same outcome.

```
$Reservation = isset($_POST['rezerwowanie']);
if ($Reservation == false) {
    $Reservation = 0;
} else
{
    $Reservation = 1;
}
```

A simpler way to accomplish this:

```
$Reservation = isset($_POST['rezerwowanie']) ? 0 : 1;
```

$Reservation will equal 0 if the user did not check the checkbox. I may have the logic backwards based on your needs, but the general idea is correct.
No if else statement required.

Comment: I believe you have the ternary backwards. If it isset, it's going to be false because of the value defined in the HTML. Shouldn't it be `? 0 : 1`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Double negative logic stuff makes code ultra weird >_>

Comment: @CoryDanielson, agreed.